# removing item from linikedList in android

Tags: java, android, doubly-linked-list

I'm basically a beginner android dev and am struggling to remove items from the linkedList i am using. The function i can't get to work is "deleteLast()", any help wold be appreciated. I am also probably quite a bit of fixing that could be done but the main issue is the as mentioned problem.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText problemView;
    private String problem;
    private TextView answerView;
    int cursorPosition = 0;
    List<String> operationsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialising views
        problemView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.problemView);
        answerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerView);

        //prevents an underline appearing in the editText
        problemView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS|InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        //initialise the the linkedList for the data structure
        operationsList = new LinkedList<>();

        problem = "";

        //create numerical buttons
        Button button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

        //create symbolic buttons
        Button buttonDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
        Button buttonMultiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply);
        Button buttonAddition = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddition);
        Button buttonSubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubtract);
        Button buttonPoint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPoint);
        Button buttonScientificNotation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScientificNotation);
        Button buttonAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer);

        //create non-displaying buttons
        Button buttonClearAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClearAll);
        Button buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        Button buttonEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEquals);

        //onClickListener for showable buttons, numbers, signs etc.
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button b = (Button) view;
                String value = b.getText().toString();

                operationsList.add(problemView.getSelectionStart(), value);
//                problem += b.getText().toString();
                cursorPosition = problemView.getSelectionStart() + 1;
                displayArray();
            }
        };

//        //onClickListener for scientific notation button since need to advance cursor more
//        View.OnClickListener listenerScientific = new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Button b = (Button) view;
//                String value = b.getText().toString();
//
//                operationsList.add(problemView.getSelectionStart(), value);
////                problem += b.getText().toString();
//                cursorPosition = problemView.getSelectionStart() + 1;
//                displayArray();
//            }
//        };

        button0.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button3.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button4.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button5.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button6.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button7.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button8.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button9.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonAddition.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonPoint.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonScientificNotation.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonAnswer.setOnClickListener(listener);

        View.OnClickListener nonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonClearAll){
                    clearAll();
                    displayArray();
                }
                if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonDelete){
                    deleteLast();
                }
                if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonEquals){

                }
            }
        };

        buttonClearAll.setOnClickListener(nonListener);
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(nonListener);
        buttonEquals.setOnClickListener(nonListener);
    }


    public void displayArray(){
        Iterator<String> iterator = operationsList.listIterator();
        String temp = "";
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            temp += iterator.next();
        }
        problemView.setText(temp);
        problemView.setSelection(cursorPosition);
    }

//    public boolean delete(){
//        stringProblemArray[spaceUsed-1] = null;
//        spaceUsed -= 1;
//        problemView.setSelection(problemView.getSelectionStart() - 1);
//        return true;
//    }
//
    public void clearAll(){
        operationsList.clear();
        cursorPosition = 0;
    }

    public void deleteLast(){
        Iterator<String> iterator = operationsList.listIterator();
        int index = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            if (index == cursorPosition-1){
                iterator.remove();
            }else {
                iterator.next();
            }
        }
        displayArray();
//        if (iterator.hasNext()){
//            for (int i =0; i == cursorPosition; i++){
//                iterator.next();
//            }
//            iterator.remove();
//        }
//        for(Iterator<String> iter = operationsList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
//            String data = iter.next();
//            if ( == rec1) {
//                iter.remove();
//            }
//        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you've just joined stackoverflow, so welcome :) one tip to improve your question, don't post your full code but rather try to post only the relevant parts, it is quite discouraging for people who want to help you if they have to read all this unrelated code

Answer (score 3):

`LinkedList` already has [`removeLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLast()) method, no need to write yours, just write

```
operationsList.removeLast()
```

that`s all.

Also if you dont want to cast your List to LinkedList (even if you are actually using LinkedList) you can delete last element using index

```
operationsList.remove(operationsList.size()-1);
```